# Two equal width columns (where the width is set by the longest one) and a third one fills the remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to make a layout like this, using CSS Grid if possible but open to other possibilities:

[image]

Basically, I want to have a container `.grid` that contains 3 elements (input, btn1, btn2). Firstly, btn1 and btn2 width should be the same and is determine by whichever element needs more space (i.e longer content). After that, the remaining element (input) should take all what is left. I came up with this snippet but for sure it cannot work.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input />
  <button>Foo</button>
  <button>Bar Bar Bar</button>
</div>
```

What is a good way to achieve this using CSS only?

Comment: I'm interested by the potential answers, but I can't personally see how this is possible without nesting the two buttons within a shared ancestor (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ph7ub2nk/).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica that's indeed what I think the answer would use but I am still hoping to see a clever solution without it.

Comment: javascript is required to check button's width to start from, an average CSS  compromise could be like  : `grid-template-columns: minmax(auto,3fr) 1 fr 1fr;` that's the most CSS would do here.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica that demo is clever even with the nesting!

Comment: js idea : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XWbyEZm if structure is to remain untouched ;) ( no javascript tag here, so just a comment )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested grid container for the buttons.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto; /* see note 1 */
}

.button-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* see note 2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input />
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar Bar Bar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid">
  <input />
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid">
  <input />
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>Foo</button>
    <button>Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. `1fr` on the first column consumes all available horizontal space, pinning the second column to the right as much as possible.
2. `1fr 1fr` on the nested columns causes the horizontal space in the sub-container to be equally divided, regardless of content width.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *hack* (yes a hack!) that relies on the fact that you know the container width.

In the below, I will consider a full-page container (width defined using `100vw`)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  margin:50px 5px;
  grid-template-columns:1fr auto;
}
/* they will overlap so the longest one will define the size of auto*/
button {
  grid-column:2;
  grid-row:1;
}

/* we translate the first one to disable the overlap*/
button:first-of-type {
  transform:translateX(-100%);
}

input {
  /* 100vw - 10px = width of the grid container 
     100% is the width of the 1fr
     ((100vw - 10px) - 100%) will be the width of the buttons
  */
  width:calc(100% - ((100vw - 10px) - 100%));
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <input >
  <button>Foo</button>
  <button>Bar Bar Bar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's both beautiful and horrible (only in the effort required to see how/why it works). :)

Comment: While I wouldn't use this in my code, you truly amaze me! Sometimes I wonder how people can come up with beautifully horrible things like this (/s)